# Notify Property Changed in Protobuf Poco Classes

Tags: c#, wpf, protocol-buffers

I have been using protobuf (SKEET generation for POCO classes), For WPF applications, we create a copy of corresponding model and then decorate with Property changed events. This looks too manual.
Is there any automated way of doing it? What's general practice followed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at [Generate WPF and Silverlight Dependency Properties using T4 Templates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35984/Generate-WPF-and-Silverlight-Dependency-Properties) from code project. It outlines how to automate a lot of that type of work using T4 templates. The article is geared for XML, however, you could adapt this method for protobuf. Note: I have not tried this.

Comment: But is it a good idea to create separate models ? Can we somehow inject notify prop changed in generated classes ?